# CSS hover selector broken

Tags: css, hover

The hover style below doesn't work as expected. Could anyone explain why?

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.floater :hover {
    left:0px;
}
</style>

<div id="floater" style="position:fixed; top:260px; left:-110px;">
    <a href="http://www.soundcloud.com/goinnative" target="_blank">
        <img title="Soundcloud" alt="Soundcloud" 
            src="http://www.imgjoe.com/x/gnsoundcloud.png" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `.` for class selector but it is really an id.

Also, generally inline styles in the `style` attribute can not be overwritten with pseudo classes. Move the CSS into the external declaration.

I would use...

```
div#floater {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 260px; 
    left: -110px;   
}

div#floater:hover {
    left: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/gN6uv/).

Answer (score 1):

Use '#' for id, not '.' - so either:

```
#floater { ... }
```

or

```
div#floater { ... }
```